# DEAP : making crossover probability a function of distance between individuals

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, deap

I am trying to implement a niching strategy with speciation. I want individuals within the same niche to be more likely to mate than individuals from different niches.

Does DEAP include a way to make the crossover probability for a pair of individuals depend on some distance between those individuals? What mating function should I use to do this?